Reproducing model with fractional polynomial predictions
I'm fitting a gamlss model using fractional polynomials. My x variable is a positive real number, including zero, and y is also positive real number ranging from 1000 to 2000.
When I try to reproduce the prediction of the linked mu term manually(for educational purposes), the results don't match those of the 'predict' function. For example, in the following model my intercept estimate is 7.1397169 (using summary function). Using the getSmo function I get the estimates and the powers of my fractional polynomials. Since I have the same power twice, the second term is followed by a log.
As far as I know, to calculate the terms manually I would need to do the following:
link(mu) = 7.1397169 -0.19476 + 0.05359new_age**(0.5) + 
           0.07165new_age**(0.5)*log(new_age)

But when I compare the results with the predict function, they don't match. For example, if new_age = 1, I get link(mu) = 6.998547, but using predict I get 6.917356.
My clue is that I always get a warning saying the my x variable has been shifted by 1. But even if I compare with new_age = 0 or new_age = 2, the results still don't match. Does anybody know where I got it wrong?
library(gamlss)
set.seed(42)

# simulated data
x <- seq(0, 95, length.out = 96)
y <- seq(1000, 2000, length.out = 96)
df = data.frame(cbind(x, y))

# fp model
model <- gamlss(formula = y ~ fp(x, npoly = 2),
                           sigma.formula = ~fp(x, npoly = 1),
                           family = GA(), data = df, 
                           method = mixed(100),
                           trace = FALSE) 
# summary to get intercept
summary(model)

# get estimates of fractional polynomials
getSmo(model)

# get powers of fractional polynomials
getSmo(model)$power

# prediction by hand
new_age = 1
mu = 7.1397169 -0.19476  + 0.05359*new_age**(0.5) + 
       0.07165*new_age**(0.5)*log(new_age)

# prediction by predict
predict(model)

